# Vue project throws error while running the project

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I created a Vue project with the Vuetify framework but it is throwing the bellow error after running the project.

Command: `npm create vuetify`

Node version: 18.15.0

System: Windows 11

Project run command: `npm run dev`

Error:

```
> demo-ty-tify@0.0.0 dev
> node --no-warnings ./node_modules/.bin/vite
 
D:\Local Data\Extra\Themes\demo-ty-tify\node_modules\.bin\vite:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
 
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
```

Trying to run the project successfully.

Comment: The tool in use is not compatible with Windows. See https://github.com/vuetifyjs/create-vuetify/issues/35

Comment: the `create-vuetify` tool was recently updated and is now broken on Windows.  The Vuetify team will need to release an update to address the issue.  In the mean time you can change the script in `package.json` to `"dev": "vite"`.  It will generate a warning that can be ignored but will still run.

Comment: @yoduh Is it good way to change manually? I installed "npm i create-vuetify@1.1.1" and it works fine. Is there any other way?

Comment: It is ok to change manually.  `"dev": "vite"` is meant to be the correct command.  I don't know what exactly generates the warning but it seems ok to ignore.  Alternatively, I think using v1.1.1 is also a fine idea.