# Error occurs when running 'npm run dev' in Vuetify project initialized with 'npm init vuetify'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

I'm new in vue3. I try to use vite+vuetify3 to dev the web.

I create a vuetify by using npm init vuetify and it works perfectly.Then I want to start to devlope by using npm run dev and it jump some error:

```
p1@0.0.0 dev
> node --no-warnings ./node_modules/.bin/vite

C:\vue\p1\node_modules\.bin\vite:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
```

The setting of creating vuetify:

```
√ Project name: ... p1
√ Which preset would you like to install? » Base (Default, Routing)
√ Use TypeScript? ... No
√ Would you like to install dependencies with yarn, npm, pnpm, or bun? » npm
```

I update the nodejs,vue,vuetify. But it still has this problem.
The vueCLI+vuetify is works.Only vite or only vueCLI also works perfectly.
Changing CMD to powershell and Git bash has same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77791522

Answer (score 4):

the **create-vuetify** is new and trying to detach from Vite but still under process.
For now, just fall back your dev script to **vite** as follows:
in your package.json update the scripts object to look like the following

```js
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint . --fix --ignore-path .gitignore"
  },
```

That should fix the problem until we get a stable **create-vuetify** tool

Comment: It's great to hear that.  You can upvote to help someone else.